# Merge two pages into pdf into one page pdf

Tags: python, pdf

There's a pdf file of two pages that I need to merge these two pages to be just one page in a new pdf output. Simply the new output pdf should be of one page
I have the following code that enables me to do that task but the problem is that the output is the two pages side by side. I need the page to be vertically one page after another inside the same page

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from PyPDF2.pdf import PageObject

pdf_filenames = ['Sample.pdf']
inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(pdf_filenames[0], 'rb'), strict=False)

page1 = inputpdf.getPage(0)
page2 = inputpdf.getPage(1)

total_width = page1.mediaBox.upperRight[0] + page2.mediaBox.upperRight[0]
total_height = max([page1.mediaBox.upperRight[1], page2.mediaBox.upperRight[1]])

new_page = PageObject.createBlankPage(None, total_width, total_height)
new_page.mergePage(page1)
new_page.mergeTranslatedPage(page2, page1.mediaBox.lowerRight[0], 0)

output = PdfFileWriter()
output.addPage(new_page)
output.write(open('MergedPDF.pdf', 'wb'))
```

Comment: Note that the second line of this code is outdated with regards to current use. [Here in the documentation for PyPDF](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/migration-1-to-2.html#imports-and-modules) it states: "PyPDF2.pdf no longer exists. You can import from PyPDF2 directly". So the second line should be currently `from PyPDF2 import PageObject`. Otherwise, you get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2.pdf'`.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it using the following code, but I welcome any ideas
Another point I need, is it possible to control the size of the page before merging?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from PyPDF2.pdf import PageObject

reader = PdfFileReader(open('Sample.pdf','rb'))
page_1 = reader.getPage(0)
page_2 = reader.getPage(1)

translated_page = PageObject.createBlankPage(None, page_1.mediaBox.getWidth(), page_1.mediaBox.getHeight()*2)
translated_page.mergeScaledTranslatedPage(page_1, 1, 0, page_1.mediaBox.getHeight())
translated_page.mergePage(page_2)

writer = PdfFileWriter()
writer.addPage(translated_page)

with open('MergedPDF.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    writer.write(f)
```

Comment: See my comment below the OP about how the second line is outdated and those adapting this now want to use `from PyPDF2 import PageObject`. Otherwise, you get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2.pdf'`.